# SVG—globalToLocal not working in FF

Tags: svg, transform

I am trying to get the transform to an element, what is working in Chrome, but throws Errors in FF.

```
var T = null;

try {
  T = element.getScreenCTM().inverse().multiply(root.getScreenCTM());

} catch (err) {
  //TypeError: element.getScreenCTM(...) is null
  T = element.getTransformToElement(root);
}

//InvalidStateError: 
//An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable
```

`root` refers to the `<svg>` element, containing the `element`.

What can be the cause for that? Thanks for any help!

Comment: @RobertLongson Could fix it right now! It was indeed a `display:none` issue. Thanks! If you answer, I will accept!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox will not calculate the transform if any elements in the hierarchy are display:none.